# MongoDB - How do I add multiple aggregations in query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Region",
      "Total Sales": {
        "$sum": "$Sales"
      },
      "Average Sales": {
        "$avg": "$Sales"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This returns the response in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Canada",
    "Total Sales": 66928.17,
    "Average Sales": 174.292109375,
  }
  .....
]
```

How do I refactor the query to get a response in the following format:

```
[{
    "_id": "Canada",
    "Sales":{"Total":66928.17, "Average":174.292109375},
  }
  ......
]
```

So far I've tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$Region",
    "Sales": {
      "Total":{
          "$sum": "$Sales"
      },
      "Average":{
          "$avg": "$Sales"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$project` to decorate the output document(s).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Region",
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$Sales"
      },
      "average": {
        "$avg": "$Sales"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "Sales": {
        "Total": "$total",
        "Average": "$average"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo PLayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6sKAHko6PZs)

Comment: is it possible to achieve this in group stage itself so that we can query for multiple keys e.g Sum of Profit etc. `$group` would become very messy otherwise

Comment: No, for each field (except _id) in $group, must be accumulator. Use `$project` to decorate desired output.